# Last cell in complex table not behaving

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I am having a hard time figuring out why the text in the last cell on each row of this complex table I am creating is not positioning correctly. As you can see from my code, the issue only occurs when I set the height of the row manually (using the [size] technique after `\\` or `\tabularnewline`).

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Everything seems to work apart from this small, but annoying issue. I know it's a "last cell on line" thing, because if I add another column, the issue transfers to the cells in that column.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X|m{1.4cm}|m{1.4cm}|m{1.4cm}|m{1.4cm}}
& & \centering{\textbf{\emph{C1}}} & \centering{\textbf{\emph{C2}}} & 
\centering{\textbf{\emph{C3}}}
    \tabularnewline
\hline

\centering{R1}
& \centering{OK}
& \centering{OK}
& \centering{OK}
& \centering{BAD}
\tabularnewline[1em]
\hline

\centering{R2}
& \centering{L1\\L2}
& \centering{OK}
& \centering{OK}
& \centering{OK}
\tabularnewline
\hline

\end{tabularx}
```

Here is a screenshot of the offending cell:

[image]

Comment: I should also add that I require line breaks, hence why I am using m{} and \centering{}. Thanks.

Comment: `\centering` is not a command with an argument; first of all remove the braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\centering{OK}` should be `{\centering OK\par}` as `\centering` does not take an argument, and the end of paragraph needs to be in its scope. that would fix your problem however a more convenient way is to remove all the `\centering` from the cells and use

```
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.4cm}
```

which inserts the command automatically into each cell, and restores the meaning of `\\` to end a table cell (`\centering` defines it to make a centred line break)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, this works. Appreciate the help.